# Heroku pg:copy not all rows copied?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I just upgraded my Postgres DB on Heroku and used pg:copy to copy everything. However in my original DB it shows there was ~32,000 rows and in the new one there are ~28,000 rows. Does this mean some rows weren't copied or is this common ?

Comment: Where do the row counts come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variance in row counts can be attributed to stale data, table bloat, or both. `pg:copy` uses `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` under the hood. If `pg:copy` completed without errors you can rest assured that data was not lost in transit.